# Matlab: How to plot data from n number of structures

Tags: matlab, dynamic, structure, field

I am working on a matlab script that has the following structures: Parameters1, Parameters2, Parameters3 etc until ParametersN. I would like to access two fields within each structure (e.g. x and y) so that I can plot the data. I would like to overlay the x and y data from each Parameters.

The problem I have at the moment is that I don't know how to access the x and y fields. I can get the names 'Parameters1','Parameters2' etc using strcat but don't know how to use the string to access the field. I have tried using whos('Parameters*') to get the structure names but have other issues.

```
text='Parameters'
for z=1:n
    S(z)=strcat(text,num2str(z))
    x=S{z}.MDT{iDLC}.Time                % problematic line
    y=S{z}.MDT{iDLC}.RotorSpeed          % problematic line
end
```

Thanks =)

Comment: I cannot stress enough that constructs like `Parameters1` should be avoided, and `Parameters(1)` should be used instead! As seen in this question simply accessing your data already becomes painful if you abuse variable names by putting enumeration in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it getting the field names, or accessing the fields that is the problem?

The eval command can be used to access the fields, the following would do `eval('Parameters1.Time')`.

```
eval([strcat(text, num2str(z)) '.Time'])
```

It would also be better to have Parameters be like an array, e.g.

```
Parameters(1) = struct("x", 1, "y", 2);
Parameters(2) = struct("x", 2, "y", 4);
```

You'd then find that you don't need strcat, and can access Parameters(z) instead.

Comment: I agree. I tried `Parameters1.('x')`, which works, but couldn't get it working when making _Parameters1_ using `strcat`. I'm using Octave, so Matlab might've worked. So I resorted to `eval`.

Comment: Mostly voted for the given advice: I cannot stress enough that constructs like `Parameters1` should be avoided, and `Parameters(1)` should be used instead! As seen in this question simply accessing your data already becomes painful if you abuse variable names by putting enumeration in them.

Comment: At the beginning of my script, I load all the data from simulations. The simulation data is stored in a structure called Parameters and in order to differentiate between the simulations I was renaming them Parameters 1,2,3 etc...which I know is a pretty ugly way to do it! I didn't know you could use an array of structures though - I've reworked things and it is much easier. Thanks, you guys are awesome!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `getfield` and `fieldnames`. Try

```
help getfield
```

and

```
help fieldnames
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what your code should probably look like:

```
hold all
for t=1:numel(Parameters)
    plot(Parameters(t).x,Parameters(t).y)
end
```

Note that this implies your usage of `Parameters(t)` rather than `Parameterst`, which greatly simplifies things and makes it more efficient.